# How to add custom error message in WebView Android?

Tags: android

Hi guys i am creating a web view app for college project

the problem is whenever the internet is not available web view shows web page not available

But what i want is to Either Display a Message or an Image saying You need to be connected to internet to use this app

So how can i Implement it

Comment: You can use Toast message and pass applicationcontext as the first parameter in the maketext method of it. That will serve the purpose

Comment: Are you looking for a non-native way? Are  you using any third party libraries like jquery mobile or sencha touch, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether Internet connection is there or not using this method

```
public class ConnectivityDetector {

private Context ctxt;

public ConnectivityDetector(Context context){
    this.ctxt = context;
}

public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null){
        NetworkInfo[] infos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (infos != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
                if (infos[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Then, in the activity which uses webview, do this

```
ConnectivityDetector cd = new ConnectivityDetector(context);
Boolean isConnected = cd.isConnectedToInternet;
// this will return true if connected and false if not.
```

Now, in your xml, create a textview with intial visibility as gone.

Now, in the activity,

```
if (isConnectedToInternet){
    //do nothing
  } else {
     webview.setVisibility(GONE);
     txtview.setText("Please connect to Internet");
     txtview.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
  }
```

You can choose your own way of showing that internet connection is not available in the else part

Comment: the if statement should be in webview activity

Comment: I am getting an error cannot resolve symbol isConnectedtoInternet

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own `WebViewClient` and treat the errors you receive:

```
 private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

}

public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
    SslError error) {

}

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        Toast.makeText(yourContext,"Check your connection",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
        //check for the type of your error in errorCode and treat errors as you wish. You can even make the webview load something else(like an image you choose) when you encounter an error.
}
};

 yourWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```